# DateFormat is displaying P1,P2,P3/A1,A2,etc instead of PM/AM

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, format, report

I am using SSRS 2008 and when I format a  date/time datafield with the expression:

```
=FormatDateTime(Fields!tour_pickup_time.Value,DateFormat.GeneralDate)
```

in the Format property for that cell I get returned, for example, 1/31/2013 4:28:12 **P1**.

What I want is obviously  1/31/2013 4:28:12 **PM**. I've searched for a fix but P1 is usually a reference to Parameter1 so my search results get muddied by that and I never get to one that references this issue.

If i leave the Format property empty then i get back the **PM** version so I'm guessing it's not an issue with my stored procedure. So how can i correct this or override it to get **PM** instead of **P1**? Anywhere that i use the GeneralDate expression I get the P1,P2,etc. issue.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, this expression displays fine for me:

```
=FormatDateTime(Now(), DateFormat.GeneralDate)
```

You can try a different expression in the Textbox instead of using `FormatDateTime`:

```
=Format(Fields!tour_pickup_time.Value, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Or you can just use the custom format string in the Format property for your Textbox:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply that definitely seems like something that works. I tried posting this but since I don't have enough rep it wouldn't allow me to.
So what I used is this for the Format Property in the Properties pane: =FormatDateTime(Fields!tour_pickup_time.Value,DateFormat.shortdate) & " " & FormatDateTime(Fields!tour_pickup_time.Value,"hh:mm:ss tt")
The first part gives me the 1/31/2013 I want,then (" ") is just a space and the third part gives me the 4:28:12 PM that I was looking for. This report will be used in other countries so I didn't want to set a fixed date format. Thanks again.